# Running ffmpeg in Terminal Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I've downloaded and unzipped ffmpeg at custom directory in my Ubuntu linux. Now I want to run this ffmpeg using terminal like I run on windows using command prompt. But everytime it says "ffmpeg: command not found". My question is how can I run ffmpeg using terminal through extracted libraries

thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: This is not a general software questions. I am asking how to execute exe like we do on windows. If you don't know the answer then there is no need to intervene.

Comment: I know the answer: ffmpeg's not in your $path. But that's not programming. That's systems configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to make sure the file has execute permissions... or just add it with `chmod +x filename`

Secondly either the executables must be on the path or you need to specify the path to the executable. What I mean by this is, under Windows if you are in a directory with an executable you can type in the executable name and it will work... this is not the case for Linux. If you are in the executable's directory you execute the command like this `./command`. The dot means you are executing a file in the current directory

Comment: Thanks Leon. this is what I want to know. I am in linux world accidently :) and is learning now.